# Sending mail with sendmail and attachment

Tags: sendmail

This is how I try to send, email with sendmail command.

With html file in body and attached zip file.

The mail received is corrupted (without body and with corrupted attachment) .

```
(
echo "From: xxxx";
echo "To: balbal@mail.com";
echo "Subject: subject";
#echo "Content-Type: text/html";
echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=MAIL_BOUNDARY"
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
 echo "--MAIL_BOUNDARY"
echo $message
cat myHtml.html
echo "--MAIL_BOUNDARY"
echo "Content-Type: application/zip"
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"
echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=zipfile.zip"
base64  zipfile.zip
echo "--MAIL_BOUNDARY--"

)> email.body

cat email.body | sendmail -t
```

Comment: usually one uses `mutt` or something that understands MIME

Answer (score 2):

This is how I get messages with attachments out of the door.  I have to execute it as root, otherwise senmail refuses a "From:" (-f option) that is not the user sending the mail.  I've replaced the echos by cat with here documents.

```
message="You will find zipfile.zip attached"
(
cat << --OEF--
Subject: $message
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
  boundary="MAIL_BOUNDARY"


--MAIL_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
  boundary="MAIL_BOUNDARY2"

--MAIL_BOUNDARY2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

$message

--MAIL_BOUNDARY2
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

--OEF--
cat myHtml.html

cat << --OEF--

--MAIL_BOUNDARY2--

--MAIL_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/zip; name=zipfile.zip
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=zipfile.zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

--OEF--
base64  zipfile.zip
cat << --OEF--

--MAIL_BOUNDARY--
--OEF--
) |  sendmail -f 'xxxx@mail.com' balbal@mail.com
```